# Rename specific rows in a column based on values in another column

Tags: r

df:

```
subset (short, short, short, short)

col1 (YB, YB, YB, XB)

col2 (0, CD, CY, 0)
```

I would like the df to be rearranged to

```
subset (short, short, short, short)

col1 (YB, YB_CD, YB_CY, XB)

col2 (0, CD, CY, 0)
```

the code I am using is:

```
df %>% mutate(Col1= ifelse(Col1=="YB" & Col2=="CD"), YB_CD, CD) %>%
          mutate(Col1= ifelse(Col1=="YB" & Col2=="CY"), YB_CY, CY)
```

but of course it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ifelse`, this can be modified with `unite`.  Replace the blank (`""` or the '0') in the 'Col2' to `NA` (`na_if`), then use `unite` on 'Col1' and 'Col3' (created from 'Col2') with NAs removed (`na.rm = TRUE`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(Col3 = na_if(Col2, '0')) %>% 
     unite(Col1, Col1, Col3, na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#   Subset  Col1 Col2
#1  short    YB    0
#2  short YB_CD   CD
#3  short YB_CD   CD
#4  short YB_CY   CY
#5  short YB_CY   CY
#6  short    XB    0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Subset = c("short", "short", "short", "short", 
"short", "short"), Col1 = c("YB", "YB", "YB", "YB", "YB", "XB"
), Col2 = c("0", "CD", "CD", "CY", "CY", "0")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

We could select unique rows with `distinct`, then use `unite` and `str_replace`

```
library(tidyverse)
distinct(df) %>% 
  unite(Col1, Col1, Col2, sep="_", remove=F) %>% 
  mutate(Col1 = str_replace(Col1, "_0", ""))
```

Output

```
  Subset  Col1 Col2
1  short    YB    0
2  short YB_CD   CD
4  short YB_CY   CY
6  short    XB    0
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `ifelse` + `paste0` (Thank @akrun's data)

```
transform(
  df,
  Col1 = paste0(Col1, ifelse(Col2 == "0", "", paste0("_", Col2)))
)
```

gives

```
  Subset  Col1 Col2
1  short    YB    0
2  short YB_CD   CD
3  short YB_CD   CD
4  short YB_CY   CY
5  short YB_CY   CY
6  short    XB    0
```